# Ao consumir um serviço, ocorre erro em campos float ou double no BD

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Quando consumo o serviço de update, ocorre esse erro:

> The 'DataLib' property on 'Liberacao' could not be set to a
>   'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value
>   of type 'System.Single'

Esse erro acontece quando

```
[Route("{id}/{value}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
                        .ToList();

            lista.ForEach(f =>
            {
                f.FlagLiberacao = 0;
                f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
            });
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Já alterei na Model o campo para:
**double, float, Single e decimal** e mesmo assim, continua o problema.
Como se o Entity ou a Lambda não reconhecesse o tipo. Sei que uma expressão lambda, faz fetch de todos os registros. Veja só, eu quero apenas atualizar dois campos, um string e outro byte. Tem como fazer uma lambda, para trazer apenas os campos em questão? Tentei dar um select e não funcionou, do tipo:

```
var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                    .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
                    //.ToList()
                    .Select(s => new Liberacao
                    {
                        FlagLiberacao = s.FlagLiberacao,
                        AutorizouReceberAtrazado = s.AutorizouReceberAtrazado
                    }).ToList();
```

Quando eu faço da forma acima, dá esse erro:

> The entity or complex type
>   'Inet.AutorizadorService.Infra.Data.Context.Liberacao' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Como falei, já tentei alterar o tipo e mesmo assim não funciona. Não tenho mais recursos.

**EDIT1**

No serviço get eu passei na DTO tudo para string e consegui resolver esse erro. Bem, tentei fazer da mesma forma, conforme abaixo:

```
[Route("{id}/{value}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
                        .Select(libera => new LiberacaoDTO
                        {
                            TipoVenda = libera.TipoVenda,
                            IdOrcamento = libera.IdOrcamento,
                            Juros = libera.Juros.ToString(),
                            Entrada = libera.Entrada.ToString(),
                            Acrescimo = libera.Acrescimo.ToString(),
                            Desconto = libera.Desconto.ToString(),
                            Mensagem = libera.Mensagem,
                            DataLib = libera.DataLib.ToString(),
                            Vencimento = libera.Vencimento.ToString(),
                            Vendedor = libera.Vendedor,
                            Cliente = libera.Cliente,
                            Filial = libera.Filial
                        })
                        .ToList();
            lista.ForEach(f =>
            {
                f.FlagLiberacao = 0;
                f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = "Testando";
            });
            contexto.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Bem, o erro desapareceu, mas tenho dois problemas com isso. Não atualizou e o parâmetro value que passo na ***URL*** está vindo ***null***. Como lista é Liberacao e não DTO, achei que poderia ser feito assim. Fico no aguardo. Passei o valor de ***AutorizouReceberAtrazado*** como pode ser visto, como um literal e mesmo assim não atualizou. Se alguém puder me dar aquela força, no aguardo.

**EDIT2**

Faltou eu postar o serviço.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Atualiza")]
    public class AtualizaController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        PedidoLiberacao liberacao = new PedidoLiberacao();

        [Route("{id}/{value}")]
        [AcceptVerbs("Put")]
        public void putItensLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            liberacao.AtualizaLiberacao(id, value);
        }
    }
```

No parâmetro string value, havia um **[FromBody]**, removi o parâmetro e agora está vindo com o valor correto, mas não faz update.

**EDIT3**

Tentei fazer assim:

```
var lib = new Liberacao();
            lib.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
            lib.FlagLiberacao = 0;
            contexto.Entry(lib).State = EntityState.Modified;

            contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Mas quando eu salvo, dá esse erro:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Agora vou fazer conforme o colega Gabriel Colleta disse

**EDIT 4**

```
List<LiberacaoDTO> lista = new List<LiberacaoDTO>();

            var lib = lista
                .Where(dto => dto.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(libera => new Liberacao
                {
                    TipoVenda = libera.TipoVenda,
                    IdOrcamento = libera.IdOrcamento,
                    Juros = float.Parse(libera.Juros),
                    Entrada = float.Parse(libera.Entrada),
                    Acrescimo = float.Parse(libera.Acrescimo),
                    Desconto = float.Parse(libera.Desconto),
                    Mensagem = libera.Mensagem,
                    DataLib = float.Parse(libera.DataLib),
                    Vencimento = float.Parse(libera.Vencimento),
                    Vendedor = libera.Vendedor,
                    Cliente = libera.Cliente,
                    Filial = libera.Filial,
                    FlagLiberacao = libera.FlagLiberacao,
                    AutorizouReceberAtrazado = libera.AutorizouReceberAtrazado
                }).ToList();

            lib.ForEach(l => 
            {
                l.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
                l.FlagLiberacao = 0;
            });

            contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Quando é feito new da classe Liberacao, o objeto é criado como um todo, mesmo que não seja inicializada todas as propriedades. Sugestão: Inicialize as propriedades que não podem ser nulas no construtor

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti, bem, os campos float, double vou iniciar no construtor da classe com 0, é isso mesmo?

Comment: Sim, imagino isso, faça o teste após essa alteração e se for isso mesmo a gente formaliza a solução.

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti, nada cara, não funcionou. Continua o erro. Vi que na Model esses campos já tem um atributo para iniciar e mesmo assim eu iniciei o construtor com esses valores.

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti, fiz uma edição de uma nova forma que encontrei. Se puder me dar uma ajuda, agradeço.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simples, o seu `DbSet` é do tipo `Liberacao` e não `LiberacaoDTO`, por isso o Entity Framework não esta entendo as alterações. Quando você faz esse new LiberacaoDTO, é um objeto totalmente novo que o Entity Framework não tem mais o tracking dele (e consequentemente, suas edições).

@Edit:
O seu maior problema é a inconsistência entre o mapeamento do seu domínio e o seu banco de dados. Se no seu banco possui uma coluna que é NULLABLE, a sua entidade que a representa no back-end deve ser também para evitar esses problemas de "System.Double ...".

Esse código resolveria se tivesse esse mapeamento correto:

```
var lib = lista
    .Where(dto => dto.IdOrcamento == id).ToList();

foreach (var item in lib)
{
    item.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = item;
    item.FlagLiberacao = 0;
}

contexto.SaveChanges();
```

Ele resolve porque, quando não faço um `Enumerable.Select()`, eu estou recebendo um `IQueryable<Liberacao>`, que é exatamente o que o Entity Framework tem conhecimento e pode fazer o tracking (Mesmo que depois você chame o `Enumerable.ToList`, o Entity mantém o tracking por referência). Nesse caso, o proprio Entity Framework entenderia que o objeto foi alterado na chamada do `ObjectContext.SaveChanges()`.

No seu caso se esta quebrando quando chama todos, o melhor a se fazer é parar um tempo e arrumar essa inconsistência.

Comment: transformar o DTO de volta para a entidade. O seu maior problema esta sendo fazer o que o pessoal do stackoverflow fala sem realmente entender o que é o que. Esse problema do float não ser nulo mesmo você já abriu uns 3 tópicos parecido. Recomendo fortemente que pare e estude pesado sobre o assunto

Comment: Não posso parar. Infelizmente esse é meu ganha pão. Sei que você está certo, mas a correria é grande demais. Não tenho como parar. Não discordo em nada de vocês, mas é a minha realidade, infelizmente. Mesmo assim, agradeço mesmo.

Comment: Vamos ajudar independente disso, foi só uma dica de amigo mesmo. Aqui não apareceu o edit 4

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e como falei, vc está certo. Tenho lido muita coisa, principalmente Xamarin. É muita coisa para aprender e pouco tempo. Sou um senhor e preciso produzir. Muitas bocas e sei que não é fácil, mas vou aprendendo muito aqui e em outros sites/foruns. Editei o post

Comment: Não entendi porque não está atualizando. Estou tentando usar o ***EntityState*** mas não consegui fazer funcionar.

Comment: O EntityState só vai funcionar em uma entidade registrada no DbSet, no seu caso Liberação.

Comment: Isso não tem nada a ver com o Sql Server? Será? Algum tipo de configuração extra, sei lá, uma coisa externo ao banco? Isso é possível?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65666/discussion-between-gabriel-coletta-and-pnet).

Comment: ***Se no seu banco possui uma coluna que é NULLABLE, a sua entidade que a representa no back-end deve ser também para evitar esses problemas de "System.Double ...".*** já fiz isso várias vezes e nesse momento setei para **float?** e o erro persiste. No banco é **float nullable**

Answer (score 1):

***RESOLVI!!***

Pessoal, o que eu fiz: Eu refiz o projeto, em realidade apenas um serviço no **VS2015**. Dessa forma, consegui resolver, mas ainda acho que no **VS2017** vai funcionar, pois fiz uma coisa no vs **VS2015** que não fiz dessa forma no **VS2017**. Acabou dando um outro erro que nada tinha a ver com a questão **float** ou **double**. Vi qual era o erro, corrigi e subi. Ao ter corrigido percebi que deu o mesmo erro e eu havia alterado onde o erro se aplicava, aí então dei um **clean** na solution e rebuildei cada projeto(3) e subi e não deu mais o erro. Troquei os campos para **double** e não **float**, depois de muita coisa, entendi que **float** no ***BD(8b)*** não corresponde ao **float** no ***.Net(4b)***. Quando eu subi, o erro no campo **DataLib** sumiu, mas apareceu nesse campo **DataRetorno**, que no banco é do tipo ***REAL*** e lendo, vi que ele é representado no **.NET** como Single. Mudei e o erro persistiu. Dei novamente um clean e apareceu em outro campo e assim fui fazendo, alterando e limpando, até que pelo serviço, consegui dar o **update**. Não considero minha, a solução encontrada. Acho que o colega **Gabriel Colleta** se faz por merecido receber o ponto, pois foi pelas dicas dele, que cheguei à solução. No momento desse post,eu não havia feito tudo isso no **VS2017**, ou seja,limpando a solution. Caso persista o erro no **VS2017**, vou fazer meus serviços pelo **VS2015** e a **App Xamarin** pelo **VS2017**. Valeu a todos mesmos. Passei o domingo todo, desde às 6:00h da manhã e vou varar a madrugada, para resolver agora a questão das notificações no Xamarin, mas isso é outro post.