# Banco sem PK, mas mapeei a PK pelo Entity. Isso dá problemas?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Estou tendo problemas com campos `float`. Bem, esse *post* vai tratar de outro assunto, mas achei que poderia de alguma forma inferir nesse problema. Parei para pensar e analisar o assunto. Esse banco é do cliente e é muito antigo. Se alguém disser pra mim, para alterar, consertar, esqueça, isso não será possível. O colega Maniero uma vez falou que está tudo errado com o banco. Bem, vi que o banco não possui PK e todos os campos são *nullable*, porem na minha classe Entity Model, eu mapeei o campo `IdLiberacao` como PK, dessa forma e vejo que não é *Identity*:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Column("ID_LIBERACAO")]
public int IdLiberacao { get; set; }
```

Eu estou trabalhando apenas com três tabelas, pode ser que no cliente mesmo(não tenho acesso) possa existir PK, isso não sei, só na segunda posso perguntar, mas a questão toda é resolver o problema com campos `float` e `double`.
Por ser um campo *nullable* no BD, achei que isso poderia trazer algum tipo de problemas, problemas esse que não sei, se de alguma forma, possa estar interferindo no comportamento do meu sistema, o qual abri esse [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237454/ao-consumir-um-servi%C3%A7o-ocorre-erro-em-campos-float-ou-double-no-bd/237509?noredirect=1#comment486774_237509). Tá tudo mal feito no banco, pelo menos aqui comigo, mas como eu disse, não tenho como alterar. Posso até corrigir o meu aqui, criando as PK's. Esse banco(Sql Server 2012) roda com um sistema desenvolvido em Clarion no cliente. Fico no aguardo de alguma resposta. A pergunta é: Em relação ao post anterior, essa situação tem a ver? Isso pode deixar o comportamento do Entity dando problemas como o que eu estou enfrentando? Tudo falado aqui, tem a ver com o *script* de criação das três tabelas que me passaram. Não passaram nenhum *script* de criação de PK ou FK ou *Index*, por isso achei que o que eu tenho aqui é uma pequena cópia do que existe no cliente, mas agora veio dúvidas. É difícil acreditar num banco sem PK. Acho mesmo que esqueceram de me passar os *script*. Dessa forma, a solução do problema em outro *post*, vai se solucionando, assim espero.

Comment: Foi feito um DER do banco de dados? É muito recomendável.

Comment: @RORSCHACH, como eu disse não tenho acesso a nada nesse banco. O meu App que estou criando, eles me passaram o script das três tabelas que serão utilizadas e mais nada. Eu não trabalho dentro da empresa, eu fico a 150Km deles, então não sei muito sobre o banco. Não posso te afirmar nada nesse banco.Criei um aqui pra mim, adicionei as tabelas(3) e estou vendo. Aqui sim, posso fazer o que eu quiser, entende. Vou criar uma PK, com identity e ver o que acontece.

Answer (score 0):

O que me intriga é o fato do banco não possuir PK. Se te passaram um script do banco de dados, a uma grande chance de na hora de exportar o banco para script, não mandaram exportar também as constraints do banco, por isso não possui PK, FK e NULL. Bom sobre as dúvidas:

> Problema de o banco não ter PK, FK e NULL e você fazer direto no código essa validação e não ter elas no banco de dados.

O problema é que o banco continua aberto a muita falha, exemplo seria se outra aplicação se comunica com o mesmo banco, as restrições de inserções/alterações/exclusões que você inseriu não vai afetar, abrindo brecha para falhas.

> Isso pode deixar o comportamento do Entity dando problemas como o que
>   eu estou enfrentando?

Em alguns casos sim e outros não, o Entity Framework não tem controle direto do seu banco de dados, o que acontece é você falar para o Entity: "Adicione esse valor NULL no campo x" e o mesmo envia para seu banco essa informação, se o seu banco não aceitar registro nulos, o mesmo vai retornar uma exceção por violação de integridade.

Já tive experiência com bancos **database first** onde o banco tinha uma FK, e o Entity Framework nem sequer sabia que aquela propriedade dele era uma FK, porque esqueceram de colocar um dataannotation `[ForeignKey]` ou um Fluent validando isso, e não foi por causa disso que não funcionava.

O melhor a se fazer é alertar seu cliente sobre o seu estado atual, transparência é tudo.

Comment: Então, o script que eu recebi não possuía PK, mas como foi de apenas três tabelas, não creio que não haja PK no BD. Já trabalhei sem FK, era um arquivo a parte que fazia as FK(texto), mas sem PK, acho quase impossível. O fato é que eu coloquei em meu exemplo agora PK e já resovi o problema que vinha tendo. Hoje gterei uma reunião com eles e colocarei vários pontos, entre eles a questão das PK's e FK's.